# Getting PL/SQL procedure result into a variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, procedure, oracleforms

I want to assign the result of PL/SQL procedure into a variable aa_idstu and use this variable in Oracle Forms pre-block trigger.

myprocedure:

```
select id_stu 
into aa_idstu 
from k_student
where id_stu=30
```

I want to use aa_idstu into Oracle Forms Builder version 6.0.8.26.0

Comment: This looks more like a query than a procedure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got everything - just put that code into `PRE-BLOCK` trigger. You'll need to `DECLARE` the variable first, though:

```
-- PRE-BLOCK trigger
declare
  aa_idstu k_student.id_stu%type;
begin
  select id_stu 
  into aa_idstu 
  from k_student
  where id_stu = 30;
end;
```

I don't know what you'll do with the variable once you got its value, but I suppose you do.

Also, pay attention to possible `NO_DATA_FOUND` and `TOO_MANY_ROWS` - if the `WHERE` condition doesn't return a single value, that `SELECT` will fail so you'll have to handle it, somehow.

Comment: can i use the name of the procedure?? like: 
declare
  aa_idstu k_student.id_stu%type;
begin
my_procedure;
end;

Comment: Sure, but you'd rather use a **function** (which returns a value) than a procedure (with an OUT parameter).

Comment: done. now i have another problem using form:
i want to hide 'TEXT428' in canvas sss if aa_idstu = 50, my code is:
if aa_idstu=50 then set_item_property('TEXT428',visible,property_false); end if;

it give me this error:
FRM-40105: Unable to resolve reference to item TEXT428

how can i solve it?

Comment: i use it in pre_block trigger

Comment: Error says that there's no item whose name is TEXT428.

Comment: but i am sure that i have this item

Comment: In that case, Forms is wrong so you should open a SR / TAR with My Oracle Suport and report a bug.

Comment: Is the item named TEXT428 in the same block that the PRE-BLOCK trigger is on?  If not, you'll need to include the block name in the set_item_property call, like this: set_item_property('BLOCKNAME.TEXT428',visible,property_false);